# PHP (Codeigniter) - Price different on Weekday and Weekend

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working on the Hotel Booking System using CI (codeigniter).

For each rooms the price for weekday and weekend are different.

So, let's say a visitor is trying to book a specific room with date range from 2 April (Thursday) - 6 April (Monday) 2020, which includes 2 nights fall on weekend.

Weekday rate is $150, and weekend rates is $200.

```
The calculation should be: 
2nd Apr - $150
3rd Apr - +150
4th Apr (weekend) - +200
5th Apr (Weekend) - +200
6th Apr -  Check out
The price should be : $700
```

Instead of $150 x 4 nights = $600 only.

I couldn't get the idea how does the logic work?

Please advise, if you have simple coding example to make it works.

I have a table for the room

I manage to track if the "date from" and "date to" is fall on weekday or weekend, but having trouble to get the price in between the date range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, let's go!
Let's say you have the checkin date, the checkout date, the price on weekdays and the price on weekends as inputs.

```
$checkInDate = '2020-03-15';
$checkOutDate = '2020-03-28';
$regularPrice = 150;
$weekendPrice = 200;
```

Fantastic! I now believe that we could calculate the difference in days between that period.

```
 $date1=date_create($checkInDate);
 $date2=date_create($checkOutDate);
 $diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);
 $numberOfTheDaysInThisPeriod = $diff->format("%a") + 1;  //We add +1 here to count the checkin date
```

> We have a total of 14 days here

Now let's calculate how many weekdays we have in that period! for that we can use this function that is fully functional.

https://gist.github.com/andygock/4be9570ee7f56d7a80f6ac01d59cebc4

This function returned me a total of 10 days a week during that period,so we have

```
$totalWeekdays = 10;
```

Perfect, now let's calculate how many days we have over the weekend. Just calculate the difference between the total number of days and the total number of weekdays.

```
$totalWeekendDays =  $numberOfTheDaysInThisPeriod - $totalWeekdays
```

> We get a total of 4 days over the weekend: 15/03 - 21/03 - 22/03 - 28/03

Now to finish we calculate the total price based on days and prices.

```
$totalPrice =   (($regularPrice * $totalWeekdays) + ($weekendPrice * $totalWeekendDays));
```

Well I haven't tested the code, but I believe that this is how I would approach the problem :) I hope it helps.

Comment: it works perfectly! thanks, but one thing, for hotel booking, we don't need to charge the check out date, which mean 

 $numberOfTheDaysInThisPeriod = $diff->format("%a") + 1;

+1 is not necessary :D, but it works for what I want, thank you very much!

Comment: I understand, in this case really just get the +1 :)
If the answer helped you I would appreciate it very much if you could mark the answer as useful https://imgur.com/aNfGxfa \o/

Comment: I had done for further test..it seems that there's some confuse of the date with the rates which maybe you can help to solve it. +1 seem necessary but, how to minus the last day? For example,$checkInDate = '2020-03-27'; $checkOutDate = '2020-03-30'; 27 nights is consider friday, weekday rates, but it calculate as weekend rates, which can be solved using +1, but 29th is supposed to be weekend rates, but it counted it as weekday rates. Any clue?

Comment: I found an easier solution to fix my problem, based on the given source code, date_diff_weekdays($from, $to), simply change your  5 ? 5 : $from_day & $to_day to 6 ? 6: $from_day & $to_day. And by changing  that, +1 can be void.

Comment: uhu! well played!!

Answer (score 0):

Simplify the problem ("*divide et impera*")

Any period of time can be divided into a "week prefix" (all days before the first Sunday, excluded), a number of "whole weeks" (Sunday to Saturday) and a "week suffix" (an incomplete week beginning with Sunday).

Any of these three periods can be missing, but one at least must be there. For example from Tuesday to the next Monday will be a prefix of T-W-T-F-S plus a suffix of S-M, with no whole weeks in between.

So you will have the week day number of the first day (0 to 6, 0 meaning Sunday); and the day of week of the last day. You will also have the number of days of the stay.

```
// Prefix: wait until Sunday
while (($beginDayNumber % 7) and ($stay > 0)) {
    // Here actually beginDayNumber can never be 0.
    if ($beginDayNumber == 0 || $beginDayNumber == 6) {
        $price += $weekendPrice;
    } else {
        $price += $normalPrice;
    }
    // Check next day
    $beginDayNumber++;
    // Day calculated, so decrement the stay.
    $stay--;
}

$beginDayNumber = 0;
// $fullWeekPrice should be 5*$normalPrice + 2*$weekendPrice,
// but who knows, there could even be a special offer.
$price += floor($stay / 7) * $fullWeekPrice;
// Now we have calculated the middle period.

// Get how many days remain.
$stay %= 7;
// Same code as above, slightly different loop condition
while ($stay > 0) {
    // Here, again, beginDayNumber can never be 6.
    if (($beginDayNumber == 0) || ($beginDayNumber == 6)) {
        $price += $weekendPrice;
    } else {
        $price += $normalPrice;
    }
    // Check next day
    $beginDayNumber ++;
    // Day calculated, so decrement the stay.
    $stay--;        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a class I created to calculate the total using an array of rates, the rates array will contain all the rates of each day of the week.

```php
/**
 * Total price calculator
 */
class TotalPrice
{
    protected $date_start = null;
    protected $date_end = null;
    protected $rates;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->rates = array_fill_keys(range(1, 7), 0.00);
    }

    public function setDateStart(DateTime $date)
    {
        if ($this->date_end && ($this->date_end < $date)) {
            throw new Exception("The end date must be greater than start date");
        }

        $this->date_start = $date;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setDateEnd(DateTime $date)
    {
        if ($this->date_start && ($this->date_start > $date)) {
            throw new Exception("The end date must be greater than start date");
        }

        $this->date_end = $date;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set rates
     * @param array $rates Must contain all week days and their rate
     */
    public function setRates(array $rates)
    {
        // Validate rates
        foreach (range(1, 7) as $key) {
            if (! array_key_exists($key, $rates)) {
                throw new Exception("Invalid rates, must include rates of all days of week");
            }
        }

        $this->rates = $rates;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set week-day rate
     * @param float $rate
     */
    public function setWeekDayRate(float $rate)
    {
        $this->rates[1] = $rate;
        $this->rates[2] = $rate;
        $this->rates[3] = $rate;
        $this->rates[4] = $rate;
        $this->rates[5] = $rate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set week-end rate
     * @param float $rate
     */
    public function setWeekEndRate(float $rate)
    {
        $this->rates[6] = $rate;
        $this->rates[7] = $rate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get the total price
     * @return float
     */
    public function getTotal(): float
    {
        $total = 0.00;
        $oneDayInterval = new DateInterval('P1D');
        $date = $this->date_start;

        do {
            $total += $this->rates[(int) $date->format('N')];
            $date->add($oneDayInterval);
        } while ($date <= $this->date_end);

        return $total;
    }
}
```

**Test 1:**

```php
// Test - 20 weekdays + 9 weekend days
$startDate = new DateTime('2020-02-01');
$endDate = new DateTime('2020-02-29');
$rates = [
    1 => 150, // Mon
    2 => 150, // Tue
    3 => 150, // Wed
    4 => 150, // Thu
    5 => 150, // Fri
    6 => 200, // Sat
    7 => 200, // Sun
];

$totalPriceCalculator = new TotalPrice();
$totalPriceCalculator->setDateStart($startDate)
    ->setDateEnd($endDate)
    ->setRates($rates);

$total = $totalPriceCalculator->getTotal();
$expectedTotal = 20 * 150 + 9 * 200;

echo "Expected total: {$expectedTotal}\n"; // Expected total: 4800
echo "Total: {$total}\n"; // Total: 4800
```

**Test 2:**

```php
// Test 2 - 20 weekdays + 9 weekend days
$startDate = new DateTime('2020-02-01');
$endDate = new DateTime('2020-02-29');
$weekDayRate = 150.00;
$weekEndRate = 200.00;

$totalPriceCalculator = new TotalPrice();
$totalPriceCalculator->setDateStart($startDate)
    ->setDateEnd($endDate)
    ->setWeekDayRate($weekDayRate)
    ->setWeekEndRate($weekEndRate);

$total = $totalPriceCalculator->getTotal();
$expectedTotal = 20 * 150 + 9 * 200;

echo "Expected total: {$expectedTotal}\n"; // Expected total: 4800
echo "Total: {$total}\n"; // Total: 4800
```

You can use this class as a library.